# Woocommerce Subscription API: How to filter by date_modified

Tags: php, woocommerce-rest-api, woocommerce-subscriptions

In my PHP Symfony app I'm trying to retrieve Woocommerce subscriptions filtered by modified date and there's no documentation available as to how "filter" parameter can be used with the API. (https://prospress.github.io/subscriptions-rest-api-docs/#list-all-subscriptions). For now all I can use is "after" and "before" for date filtering which seem to be using subscription created date.

```
use Automattic\WooCommerce\Client;
use Automattic\WooCommerce\Admin\Notes\WooCommerceSubscriptions;

$wc_subscription = new Client($this->getParameter('woocommerce_url'), $this->getParameter('woocommerce_key'), $this->getParameter('woocommerce_secret'), ['version' => 'wc/v1',]);

$subs = $wc_subscription->get('subscriptions', ['page' => 1, 'per_page' => 100, 'filter' => ['date_modified' => '2021-02-01']]);
```

This returns extremely high record number which is incorrect because only a few subscriptions have got updated.

How can I filter by "date_modified" or any other field in the subscription response object.

Answer (score 0):

This from the WC rest posts controller might help:

```
/**
 * Filter the query arguments for a request.
 *
 * Enables adding extra arguments or setting defaults for a post
 * collection request.
 *
 * @param array           $args    Key value array of query var to query value.
 * @param WP_REST_Request $request The request used.
 */
 $args = apply_filters( "woocommerce_rest_{$this->post_type}_query", $args, $request );
 $query_args = $this->prepare_items_query( $args, $request );
```

It seems you could use the "woocommerce_rest_shop_subscription_query" to adjust the args prior to the WP_Query. And, since you get the request as a param, you can base your adjustment on the precise values wanted.

Remember that the WP_Query date query needs to have the column value in it to use the modified date rather than post date.

```
'date_query' => [
    'column' => 'post_modified',
    'after'  => [
        'year'  => 2021,
        'month' => 2,
        'day'   => 15,
    ],
],
```